# UITableview with custom cells

Tags: swift, uitableview

Hi I am having a problem in my app

**I am using UITableView with the custom cell. In each cell, I have a
checkbox, when I check it, it is getting the cell’s element into a
set. Everything is working correctly except a small problem.**

The Problem:

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bbsa.gif)

**As in the image when I click on the first row, the 10th row is seeming
like checked. The image changed to checked but in practice, it did
not occur in my set.**

Here is the related part of the code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TblCell
    cell.labelInCell.text = tableData[indexPath.row]//data.myFunc().myset[indexPath.row]
    cell.checkBoxInCell.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.checkBoxInCell.addTarget(self, action: Selector("yourCheckBoxClicked:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    // cell.images.image = UIImage(named: tableData[indexPath.row])
    // if images name is same as in tableData put it in front of label

    return cell
}

func yourCheckBoxClicked(cbx:UIButton){

    let picked = self.tableData[cbx.tag]
    if choosenSet.contains(picked) {
        choosenSet.remove(picked) // uncheck
    } else {
        choosenSet.insert(picked) // check
    }
    print(choosenSet)

}
```

Number of rows in section ->

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return tableData.count
    }
```

Checkboxes class ->

```
class checkBox: UIButton {


    //images
    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "button_checkboxFilled")
    let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "button_checkboxEmpty")

    // Bool Property
    var isChecked : Bool = false {
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true{
                self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }else {
                self.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:" , forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }


    func buttonClicked (sender:UIButton) {
        if (sender == self) {
            if isChecked == true {
                isChecked = false

            }else {
                isChecked = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is inside your numberOfRowsInSection override?

Comment: UITableView reuse cell objecs for performance enhancement. Therefore when a cell appears on screen it might be possible that some of its attributes have values from a previously onscreen cell.  What code do you perform on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` ? Also, do you use the `setSelect()`method of UITableViewCell? If so, you might need to refresh the correct selected state of the cell there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of cells reusage. You should just add this line to your `func tableView(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` method:

```
cell.checkBoxInCell.isChecked = choosenSet.contains(tableData[indexPath.row])
```

Comment: what do you mean by .checked I don't have a property like that ?

Comment: How do you make this checkBox checked then?

Comment: see in question I have a function named yourCheckboxClicked :)

Comment: But there is no any code there for changing interface. You should also have a code for displaying a dot inside the checkbox somewhere. What type does your checkBox have?

Comment: yes yes, I've another class for it, should I include it ?

Comment: I Will go crazy. I couldn't do it. I am not able to reach isChecked in tableView(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath) method ;(

Comment: Why? What does compiler say?

Comment: Nothing... I was not able to go through that part :) . Ok maybe it is about my classes, I declared checkBoxInCell in table's class and made its type checkBox. I will add photo see now

Comment: Ok, I see that your checkBoxInCell type is `UIButton`, but should be `checkBox` in Interface builder as well as in code. Then you'll see this `isChecked` method in it.

Comment: Ow wait. I got it wait let me try

Comment: YEEEESSSSSS GOTT it . :)

Answer (score 0):

Your cells are reused, quick solution which will work fine as your table view doesn't have a lot of cells:

```
let cell: TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell" + String(indexPath.row)) as! TblCell
```

If your tableView has many rows than you should have "cell" identifier and update the selection style on each `cellForRowAtIndexPath` call

Comment: This is a prototype so I will have more rows in original program.

Comment: Also it is not working , I am getting fatal error when I changed mine with yours.

Comment: Error is because cells were not registered for such reuse identifier. Seems the only option for you is to update the cell selection style on each cellForRowAtIndexPath call